# Why does site not load font stylesheet in www. site with firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Site in progress: http://stonetoolsupply.com

When I view the site http://stonetoolsupply.com in Firefox 26 on OSX 10.6.8 the fonts load correctly, but when I view this site as http://www.stonetoolsupply.com in Firefox 26 on OSX 10.6.8 the fonts aren't loaded and my text is unstyled. Why is this happening? I'm so stumped! Thanks!

Font stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'avenir_lt_std35_light';
src: url('avenirltstd-light-webfont.eot');
src: url('avenirltstd-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('avenirltstd-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('avenirltstd-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('avenirltstd-light-webfont.svg#avenir_lt_std35_light') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
font-family: 'avenir_lt_std85_heavy';
src: url('avenirltstd-heavy-webfont.eot');
src: url('avenirltstd-heavy-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('avenirltstd-heavy-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('avenirltstd-heavy-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('avenirltstd-heavy-webfont.svg#avenir_lt_std85_heavy') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'helvetica_neue_lt_st25ultraLt';
src: url('helveticaneueltstd-ultlt-webfont.eot');
src: url('helveticaneueltstd-ultlt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-ultlt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-ultlt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-ultlt-webfont.svg#helvetica_neue_lt_st25ultraLt') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'helvetica_neue_lt_std45_light';
src: url('helveticaneueltstd-lt-webfont.eot');
src: url('helveticaneueltstd-lt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-lt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-lt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-lt-webfont.svg#helvetica_neue_lt_std45_light') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
font-family: 'helvetica_neue_lt_std35_thin';
src: url('helveticaneueltstd-th-webfont.eot');
src: url('helveticaneueltstd-th-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-th-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-th-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('helveticaneueltstd-th-webfont.svg#helvetica_neue_lt_std35_thin') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Links to css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stonetoolsupply.com/v/vspfiles/splash/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stonetoolsupply.com/v/vspfiles/splash/fonts/stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, instead of a link to a  site in progress (which will change)

Comment: Does including the `www` in your CSS href help?

Comment: Oh, and FWIW, FF 26 on Win7 seems to display either URL for your site correctly.

Comment: You don't need the domain in the href, just do `/v/vspfiles/splash/fonts/stylesheet.css`

Comment: @Charlie74 yes this is true, it also displays fine in Chrome 32. Nick R thanks for the tip. Unfortunately none of these suggestions have worked. Do you think this could be solved with a 301 redirect?

Comment: May be same-domain issue. Try putting font sheet first ... and you have a loooot of fonts - have you added up the file size to see the page weight? Two or three are usually enough - you have five - probably over a MB.

Comment: both sites work for me. Have you flushed the cache?

Comment: I have a js error - line 44 /v/vspfiles/splash//img/bg.jpg - did you mean to have two slashes?

Comment: @Ruskin you were right lol just a browser cache did the trick. I thought I did this already, but I guess not. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user2731260 Can you write an answer to this question yourself? Otherwise, it will always keep showing up in the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments above - make sure you have refreshed the browser cache (also note that I am getting a javascript error in the F12 console)